# How do I fax out an envelope using DocuSign for Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

We have a very small number of customers who do not have email addresses, but we would still like to work with these clients through the Salesforce workflow we've set up.

I've found that DocuSign has the "Fax Out" feature available, but I can't find any information about using it in Salesforce. How can I use the DocuSign "Fax Out" feature from DocuSign for Salesforce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fax out feature is not available in the DocuSign for Salesforce app, unfortunately.  I believe that means you're main options are:

1. Use the DocuSign Console on the particular envelopes where you need to use the fax feature.
2. Use another DocuSign Integration or Connector that has the fax feature.
3. Write a custom API integration to add the fax feature.

With DocuSign's API you can integrate DocuSign functionality into any system that can successfully make web request to an external service, though you would need to setup an integration account with DocuSign that your integration would work out of.